# Socket.BeginSendTo and Socket.BeginReceiveFrom is not sending or receiving the data

Tags: unity-game-engine, sockets, udp

I am trying to make a dedicated server for my new game using UDP sockets. I am using `Socket.BeginSendTo()` and `Socket.BeginReceiveFrom()` methods in order to send my data.

I am receiving the callbacks from both the methods, but when I am trying to `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer)` it is not showing me any strings. I am not sure if there is a problem while sending, or if there is a problem while receiving.

I know that UDP does not guarantee the transmission, that's why I tried to send my data more then twice more like 10 times. Each time, I receive a callback that the data is sent on the client side and the data is received on the server side. But, as I said, when I am trying to read the data using `Encoding`, it shows nothing. I tried to do a string null or empty check while receiving the data. It said that the string is not empty, but when I try to `Console.WriteLine()`, it showed nothing in the console.

Here is the client code, where I am sending the data to the server:

```
public void SendMessage(Activity activityCode, String inputedString) //I am changed this
{
    byte[] data = readMessage.WriteData(activityCode, inputedString);
    if(data != null)
    {
        Debug.Log(data.Length); //this returned 11
        clientSocket.BeginSendTo(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, serverEndpoint, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);
    }
    
    Array.Clear(readMessage.data, 0, readMessage.data.Length);
}

private void OnSend(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Debug.Log("sent"); //I am getting this callback in my console
}
```

Here is my server code, where I am receiving the data:

```
private void StartReceiveingData()
{
    try
    {
        if (!serverSocket.IsBound)
        {
            serverSocket.Bind(localServerIPEndPoint);
        }

        IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        //The epSender identifies the incoming clients
        EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;

        serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(StaticTest.byteData, 0, StaticTest.byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), epSender);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    StaticTest.printDData();
    IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;
    serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epSender);
    
    StartReceiveingData();
}
```

And here is where I am reading the data:

```
static public class StaticTest
{
    static public byte[] byteData = new byte[1024];
    
    public static void printDData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reding the received data" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteData));
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE**: I tried this code, but it still does not work:

```
private void StartReceiveingData()
{     
    try
    {
        if (!serverSocket.IsBound)
        {
            serverSocket.Bind(localServerIPEndPoint);
        }

        IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        //The epSender identifies the incoming clients
        EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;

        serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), epSender);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;
    int numData = serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epSender);
        
    if (!clientList.ContainsKey(epSender))
    {
        Client client = new Client(epSender);
        clientList.Add(epSender, client);     
    }
    if(clientList.TryGetValue(epSender, out Client client1))
    {
        string _receivedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteData, 0, numData);
        Console.WriteLine(_receivedData + " Data that came");
        //client1.RecieveDataFromMyGameObject(_receivedData);
    }

    StartReceiveingData();
}
```

And here is where I am reading the data:

```
public string TakeActions(string _recivedData)
{
    int activityInput = Convert.ToInt32(_recivedData.Substring(0,1)); //there is an error
    ActivityRequest activity = (ActivityRequest)activityInput;
    Console.WriteLine("Current activity Number : " + activity);

    if(activity == ActivityRequest.SetupClient)
    {
        SetupClientDataActivity.setupClientData(client,_recivedData.Substring(1,_recivedData.Length-1));
    }
    else if(activity == ActivityRequest.MatchMaking)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Asking Room manager to get into a room");
        // roomManager.AddAClientToARoom(client); 
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please don't rewrite your question/code in anvalidates answers already given to you. I have rolled back your edit and reapplied it in a more appropriate manner for you.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I tried what you said me to do ,but it didn't work. I tried to print the length of the string; It showed me 11, the same number of byte that were transfer. The string is still full of spaces I don't know why

Comment: it is hard to diagnose since you haven't shown what the data actually looks like. What is the content of `inputedString`? What is the raw content of `data` before sending it? What is the raw content of `byteData` after receiving it? What does `readMessage.WriteData()` do with the data? Without a [mcve], there is really no way to know why your data is not what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OnSend` callback needs to call `Socket.EndSendTo()` to finish the send operation and tell you whether the operation was successful or not.

Your `OnReceive` callback is calling `Socket.EndReceiveFrom()`, but you are ignoring its result, and you are trying to print the `byteData` before calling `EndReceiveFrom()` to finish the read operation and tell you how many bytes were actually written into `byteData`.

Try this instead:

```cs
public void SendMessage(Activity activityCode, String inputedString)
{
    byte[] data = readMessage.WriteData(activityCode, inputedString);
    if (data != null)
    {
        Debug.Log($"sending {data.Length} bytes");

        try
        {
            clientSocket.BeginSendTo(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, serverEndpoint, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    
    Array.Clear(readMessage.data, 0, readMessage.data.Length);
}

private void OnSend(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        int numBytes = clientSocket.EndSendTo(ar);
        Debug.Log($"sent {numBytes} bytes");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

```cs
private void StartReceiveingData()
{
    try
    {
        if (!serverSocket.IsBound)
        {
            serverSocket.Bind(localServerIPEndPoint);
        }

        IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;

        serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(StaticTest.byteData, 0, StaticTest.byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), epSender);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        IPEndPoint ipeSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)ipeSender;
        int numBytes = serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epSender);
    
        StaticTest.printDData(numBytes);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    StartReceiveingData();
}
```

```cs
static public class StaticTest
{
    static public byte[] byteData = new byte[1024];
    
    public static void printDData(int numBytes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received data: {0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteData, 0, numBytes));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I tried what you said ,but for some reason it didn't work. I updated my post with new script. Can you take a look and tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Look at this : [link] (https://imgur.com/a/ymPGC1o)